# FluentBit - Parsing from Path_Key

Tags: parsing, syslog, fluentd, fluent-bit

Currently im adding the filepath using Path_Key. I am trying to grab multiple variables that exist in the Path_key.

```
/var/log/containers/**Application_Name**-**Application_Version**.log
```

Is it possible to extract these values from an existing field mapping?

Answer (score 2):

For extracting values for use in the `Tag` it is pretty straight forward, you would have an input like:

```
[INPUT]
    Name  tail
    Path  /var/log/containers/*-*.log
    Path_Key  filename
    Tag <appname>.<appversion>
    Tag_Regex  /(?<appname>[^-]+)-(?<appversion>[^.]+).log$
```

The `Tag_Regex` is used to set the `<appname>` and `<appversion>` variables that can be used to set the `Tag`.

---

As for setting these sort of values in a field in the log entry I couldn't find any "native" way to do it. However I was able to achieve something similar by using a [Lua filter](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/lua):

```
[INPUT]
    Name  tail
    Path  /var/log/containers/*-*.log
    Path_Key  filename

[FILTER]
    Name  lua
    Match  *
    script  helper.lua
    call  extract_app_fields
```

which invokes the the `extract_app_fields` function in the `helper.lua` file:

```
function extract_app_fields(tag, timestamp, record)
    retcode = 0
    filename = record['filename']
    
    if filename ~= nil then
        appname = filename('/([^-]+)-[^.]+\.log')
        appversion = filename('/[^-]+-([^.]+)\.log')
        
        if appname ~= nil then
            record['appname'] = appname
            retcode = 2
        end
        
        if appversion ~= nil then
            record['appversion'] = appversion
            retcode = 2
        end
    end
    
    return retcode, timestamp, record
end
```

The `extract_app_fields` function extracts the `appname` and `appversion` from the `filename` and updates the fields in the `record` if they can be determined.

*Note: I'm very much a Lua novice, so there may be a better way to do this using Lua.*